# Ordering the wildcard completions filenames in Vim first by file-extension (then alphabetical order)

Tags: vim

Currently, the wildcard completions for filenames (after pressing `:e` or `:new`, etc.) in command line mode is sorted alphabetically, as if all the filenames are strings. This is understandable, but for one who keeps editing `*.tex` files, the following is desired:

1. Upon completion of initials of filename, first show me the `*.tex` file.
2. Let the `*.log` files be placed in the second place.

Note that, I do not want the wildcard to ignore `*.log` files completely, as it used by other statistical softwares for logs.

Any thought on how to elevate the priority of `*.tex* files?

All the best,

-Linfeng

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, Vim has the `'suffixes'` option. From `:help 'suffixes'`:

> Files with these suffixes get a lower priority when multiple files match a wildcard.

So, just set

```
:set suffixes+=.log
```

and log files will appear after any other file extension.

There's also `'wildignore'` for completely ignoring certain files. Anything beyond that would require overriding the `:edit` etc. commands with custom ones that implement a custom filename completion, so that would be cumbersome and quite involved.